# Github clone - how to mirror with lfs remote: Internal Server Error

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm trying to create a new repo based of and existing one, the existing one have LFS. These are the commands I'm executing

```
git clone --bare https://oldrepo
cd oldrepo
git lfs fetch --all
git push --mirror https://newexistingrepo
Enumerating objects: 170024, done.
Counting objects: 100% (170024/170024), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (56305/56305), done.
Writing objects: 100% (170024/170024), 178.28 MiB | 2.34 MiB/s, done.
Total 170024 (delta 107837), reused 170024 (delta 107837), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (107837/107837), done.
remote: Internal Server Error
Everything up-to-date
```

And nothing is copied to the new repo, any ideas?

UPDATE:
I managed to mirror the repo by modify this code from AWS to incremental migrations to code commit (works for github)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-push-large-repositories.html#how-to-push-large-repositories-sample

Comment: *Internal Server Error* is coming from the remote. You'll have to go check the logs *on* the remote to get something more specific.

Comment: @torek this is github.com

Comment: In that case,  contact GitHub support.